# reduction from partition to N3DM or balanced 3 partition problem

Tags: np-complete, np, p-vs-np, partitions, subset-sum

I want to know how can I reduce Subset Sum or Partition problem to N3DM problem in which each set has exactly 3 elements and same sum.

N3DM Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_3-dimensional_matching